# HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive vs ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

Can anyone explain what is the difference/implication for sample code below assuming i have a HttpWebRequest object "request"?

```
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 1000, 5000);
```

In sample above, i set both to True. What if i set one to True and another to False? What is the implication?

Answer (score 7):

These are 2 different features.

[HTTPWebRequest.KeepAlive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx) refers to the [HTTP persistent connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) feature where the socket can be re-used for a subsequent HTTP request.

[ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.settcpkeepalive.aspx) refers to the [TCP keepalive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive#TCP_keepalive) feature which keeps a socket from closing after a long period of inactivity, and provides the ability to detect if the connection was dropped during a period of inactivity.

It is safe to use both, or neither, or any combination of the two.  I think it would be atypical to use TCP keepalive on an HTTP connection though.  I speculate that one might use it if there was some kind of operation where the server is not obligated to respond until an event happens.  Ex: like long polling over HTTP.

Comment: While your assumption is totally correct, Chrome does send TCP keepalives - while other tools don't. This means that API requests that take a long time to be answered may time out on one browser/tool while they work perfectly in Chrome. Same with Postman, the standalone version will time out, the discontinued Chrome extension uses TCP keepalive and therefore does not time out.